# Connecting remote servers via VPN

Tags: vpn

I have several servers hosted by few server hosting companies. Each server has its own public IP. I have app server, DB server, web server, etc. What I wanted to do is connect them into private network, altought they are physicaly in different locations. I was looking for some solutions and I came up with VPN. But I'm still confused with some VPN concepts.

For example, I would like to let OpenSSH server listen on virtual private network interface and accept only SSH connections within private network. So in order to connect over SSH to server, I would have to connect into private network first, and then connect to that server over SSH. 
Furthermore, I would like to let DB server listen on virtual private interface and let other servers to send SQL queries over private network.

Is it possible to connect those remote servers to private network using OpenVPN for those use cases, I mentioned earlier?

I have studied some OpenVPN examples, but but I'm not clear which server should be OpenVPN client and which should be OpenVPN server in my example ?

Comment: I would recommend setting up a full-mesh IPsec network instead of VPN. This way each server can communicate with any other server directly, without needing to go through a central hub. Additionally, IPsec is much more well-suited to "infrastructure" VPN than OpenVPN is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect those remote servers to private network using OpenVPN for those use cases, I mentioned earlier?

Yes

> but I'm not clear which server should be OpenVPN client and which should be OpenVPN server in my example

Choose one to be a server and make the rest clients. You could even make a separate machine the VPN server and have everything else as clients. The world is your mollusc.